# How to read file asynchronously for module with then-yield

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm trying to load a secret for use with **koa-jsonwebtoken**.

here's  the relevent bits from my koa server:

```
import jwt, { fromAuthorizationHeader } from 'koa-jsonwebtoken';
import {serverCredentials} from './auth'
//...
console.log('loaded serverCredentials' + JSON.stringify(serverCredentials))    
app.use(jwt({ secret: serverCredentials.shared, extractToken: fromAuthorizationHeader }));
```

and my auth is:

```
import ty from 'then-yield'
import md5 from 'md5'
import Promise from 'bluebird'
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

const serverCredentials = ty.spawn(function* () {
  let src
  try {
    console.log('trying')
    src = yield fs.readFileAsync('./serverCredentials.json','utf8')
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('Error when opening serverCredentials file: ' + e.message);
    throw e
  }
  console.log('serverCredentials: ' + src)
  return JSON.parse(src)
})

export {serverCredentials}
```

but my log says:

```
trying
loaded serverCredentials{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}
```

instead of the server key.

Comment: for debuggin purposes, have you tried `fs.readFileAsync('../serverCredentials.json','utf8').then(function(res){ console.log(res) })` ?

Comment: commenting out the last line and doing that did trigger the catch for ENOENT .. but I've corrected the path now and still same problem. updating

Comment: Given you're using Bluebird, why opt for then-yield instead of `Promise.coroutine`? And given you're using a transpiler, why not simply use `async`/`await` right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serverCredentials` is a promise for your JSON-parsed object. You will need to wait for it:

```
import jwt, { fromAuthorizationHeader } from 'koa-jsonwebtoken';
import {serverCredentials as credentialsPromise} from './auth';

credentialsPromise.then(serverCredentials => {
    console.log('loaded serverCredentials' + JSON.stringify(serverCredentials))    
    app.use(jwt({secret: serverCredentials.shared, extractToken: fromAuthorizationHeader}));
});
```

Comment: ahh, okay the. that looks logical. I was really spun a round writing this, forgot some promise basics for a second. thank you.